# Rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'up'

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble migrating up.  Thanks for sharing your time, and I appreciate the help!

- Windows 7(64 bit)
- Ruby: 1.9.2p290
- Rails: 3.2.3
- MySQL: 5.5.24

```
> rake db:migrate up VERSION=20120529170841 --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'up'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in
`[]'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in
`invoke_task'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `
block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `
each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `
block in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
`standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `
top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `
block in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
`standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `
run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:23:in `'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=2012052917
```

instead of (`rake db:migrate up ...`)

Comment: Yes, that totally fixed it.  Thank you!